# CRLF injection/HTTP response splitting vulnerabilities

Tags: error

We're hosing a site built with EE v2.10.1. As part of our hosting agreement I’ve had to run a vulnerability scan.

The scan found 23 CRLF injection/HTTP response splitting vulnerabilities.

Is this likely to be an EE issue or as a result of the way the site is coded?

I have the report that I could send to a EE support contact if it helps.

Thanks

Wayne.

Here is an example of the error in the report.

`Affected items

/

Details
Path Fragment input was set to SomeCustomInjectedHeader: injected_by_wvs
Injected header found:
SomeCustomInjectedHeader: injected_by_wvs

GET
/index.php/template-group/template-name/some-title-here%0dSomeCustomInj
ectedHeader:%20injected_by_wvs-2013 HTTP/1.1
Referer: http://domain.com
Cookie: exp_last_visit=1127726290; exp_last_activity=1443086299;
exp_tracker=%7B%220%22%3A%22font-awesome.css%22%2C%221%22%3A%22corporate%2Fcorporate-inf
ormation%2Fcharity%22%2C%222%22%3A%22corporate%2Fcorporate-news%2Ftite-here%22%2C%223%22%3A%22corporate%2Fnews%22%2C%224%22%3A%22
good2freeze%2Fdetail%22%2C%22token%22%3A%2200636beb8451791776252ab2ef30c264%22%7D;
exp_csrf_token=13e5fd3fee3d9d10383fc125f3cb6ef2197cc286; cb-enabled=accepted
Host: www.domain.com
Connection: Keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.21 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.21
Accept: */*`

The scan was run on a developed site using Acunetix Vulnerability Scanner

Comment: This is kind of vague. Could you post a few example CRLF issues the report found? I'm intrigued, but honestly in doubt that EE is at fault. They **never** had a major breach of their framework. Was the scan run after some development, or is the scan on a vanilla, untouched install?

Comment: What software did you use to run the scan? Depending on the settings, they can throw lots of false positives. It could be a lot of things. Does it tell you where it found the vulnerabilities?  I've had scanners tell me there were vulnerabilities on completely blank pages.

Comment: Well if the site is developed (I mean no offense...), and that error there is tracked to a template that obviously Ellis didn't develop, I think the culprit here isn't EE... at least in the example you posted.

Comment: This is the scanner I used http://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/register-online-vulnerability-scanner/ The vulnerabilities where found in: Path input .php/ was set to SomeCustomInjectedHeader: injected_by_wvs